# temp table FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM #Bla FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

which gives me this:

```
<_x0023_Bla>
  <Id>11</Id>
  <Name>XYZ</Name>
</_x0023_Bla>
<_x0023_Bla> 
  <Id>14</Id>
  <Name>X &amp; Y</Name>
</_x0023_Bla>
```

Is there a way to suppress *x0023*? The intention is to pass this as NVARCHAR(MAX) to a sproc and then reassemble the table #Bla there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table alias.

```
SELECT * FROM #Bla as Bla FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```